# Comparing Records within a recordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if anyone can tell me the general VBA syntax that is required when you are comparing records from one record set to another recordset?

So here is the situation:

Let's say your comparing bank transactions - you have a name, transaction date, amount in your table master.  You get your monthly statement in email and you import that and only want to bring in the transactions that are not present in the table master.  Therefore you compare name, transaction date, and amount.  If it is present in the tblMaster you don't import this.

I want to write this in VBA or SQL as a routine for a database that I am building not just a one time query.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `JOIN` statement.

I would read up on them here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp